# Android DatePicker bug on maxDate

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have created a DatePickerDialog and I am trying to limit the picker to the **max date of "today"** (currently: 2020, 13 Jul), like this:

```
DatePickerDialog(
    activity,
    OnDateSetListener { _: DatePicker?, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
        selectedBirthday.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
    },
    1980, 7, 2
).apply {
    datePicker.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis() // max date = today
}.show()
```

The dialog opens correctly with default data ("1980, Aug 02").

However, I have found a bug when "1980, Aug 02" is selected and **I change the year** to 2020: The dialog then shows **"2020, Aug 02" on top** ignoring the *maxDate* limit setup on the *datePicker*, but **the calendar below is correctly limited** to July 13.

Screenshot:
[image: Android DatePickerDialog ignores maxDate]

If I click on "OK" button, the year, monthOfYear and dayOfMonth returned on my DateSetListener are **2020, Aug, 02**, which is a **future date** from what I wanted. Is there any workaround to avoid this bug on the DatePickerDialog with the maxDate being ignored?

Comment: Please try my answer. Let me know if it's not worked?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the issue. One thing you can try is to update selected date right below the line where you set the maximum date inside of `apply` block: `updateDate(1980, 7, 2)`.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Feel free to copy and paste the code to reproduce it! The steps when the dialog appears are:
1. Select a past year (for example: 1980)
2. Select a "future" month&day (for example: 02, Sept)
3. Select the current year (2020)

Comment: @ShaluTD Sorry, it didn't...

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but at least I can provide more details: I have just reproduced this bug in an app I am developing. It appears on Android 11 (RSR1.201013.001), but not on android 12 (SQ1A.220105.002).

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug. There is a [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169602180) recorded 2020-09-29 and still open (in assigned state) as of 2022-02-08.

A [similar bug tracker entry with the same issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124647440) created 2019-02-19 was closed on 2019-12-04 as "won't fix" due to it being low priority.

I am sorry to say this, but I believe this is not going to be fixed.

However, what you can do is extend the `android.app.DatePickerDialog` to introduce a fix yourself:

```kotlin
class MyDatePickerDialog(context: Context) : DatePickerDialog(context) {

    override fun onDateChanged(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        val newDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply { set(year, month, dayOfMonth) }
        val minDate = Date(datePicker.minDate)
        val maxDate = Date(datePicker.maxDate)
        newDate.time = minOf(maxDate, maxOf(minDate, newDate.time))
        super.onDateChanged(
            view,
            newDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            newDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            newDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `Date().getTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`

```
DatePickerDialog(
    activity,
    OnDateSetListener { _: DatePicker?, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
        selectedBirthday.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
    },
    1980, 7, 2
).apply {
    datePicker.maxDate = Date().getTime() // max date = today
}.show()
```

Comment: `Date()` constructor uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` to set time value in milliseconds. It will not work.

Comment: It did not work but thanks for the try! It seems that the maxDate is setup correctly since it is blocked on the calendar and it does not allow me to check a future day or month if I'm on 2020 year. But if I select a "future month" in a past year and then change to the current year, the "bug" shows up.